# How are Quantum Dot molecules formed and what properties do they hold apart differently from singular quantum dots?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, electronic-configuration, materials

I am trying to understand the science and phenomena behind the function and operation of quantum dot molecules, but the only articles I run into talk about the synthesis of them. Could this be explained to me? Thank you

Comment: Did you read Wikipedia? There is nothing unique about quantum dots (QDs).  QDs are nanometer sized crystals of semiconductors with some interesting optical properties.

Answer (score 3):

A) *There are quite a few different ways* by which  Quantum Dot molecules are formed. As M.Farooq sir has said , you can check about them on Wikipedia or even on many different sites. Let me take you step by step.

B)**Quantum dots (QDs)** are man-made nanoscale crystals that that can transport electrons. When UV light hits these semiconducting nanoparticles, they can emit light of various colors.

This article also talks about their **function** https://www.nanowerk.com/what_are_quantum_dots.php .

C) Now , you say that articles only talk about their synthesis and your Q above is how they are formed ? And inside the title , you Q is again different.

What is **Synthesis* ? Synthesis means to combine a number of different pieces into a whole.

Synthesis or formation are more or less , the same thing. If you see.

Example : Synthesis or formation of molecules from atoms. General statement but mean same thing. Experiment it yourself by searching difference between formation and synthesis.

D) Now , how are they **formed** ?

1. Quantum dot molecules are formed by coherent tunneling between two individual quantum dots. The coherent tunneling leads to the formation of delocalized states that are truly molecular in nature, with bonding and antibonding orbital states.

For more details : https://sites.udel.edu/dotygroup/home/quantum-dot-molecules/

Now , you must understand. Just like molecules are formed from atoms. This is a general meaning. Similarly, there are different kinds of quantum dot molecules formed by different methods or procedure which mostly come from the same basic meaning as I have written above.

For example : How are graphene quantum dots formed ?

Pyrolysis is one of the simplest methods of synthesizing graphene quantum dots. In this method, GQDs are formed via carbonization of small organic molecules

https://www.intechopen.com/books/smart-drug-delivery-system/graphene-quantum-dots-from-emergence-to-nanotheranostic-applications. For more details.

Your question inside what you have written is completely different from your title.